# Criteria for considering questions 'duplicates' seem to need improvement

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

Repeatedly I have noticed that questions on HSM stack exchange are getting closed as 'duplicates' when it is at least highly arguable that they are anything but duplicates.

The need for improved criteria for finding 'duplication' emerges most clearly from examples.

The most recent example is closure of the question "What made Newton realize that the law of gravitation was 'universal'?" ('Q1')

The grounds for closure of Q1 as a duplicate are that the question "already has answers" at "Did Newton develop the concept of gravity first for falling objects or for celestial motion?" ('Q2'.)

But inspection of Q2 and its answers shows that the *universal* character of gravitation was not considered anywhere in those answers.  These answers to Q2 could hardly be considered responsive to Q1.

When disparate questions are classed as 'duplicates', it does call into question the good sense of the criterion that is being operated.

Is there any way of getting the current criterion reconsidered?